# How do I Cancel the Momentum of an Object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a kill zone at the bottom of my level in my 3D platformer, but when my rolling ball get respawned using `transform.position` I keep my momentum. How do I cancel all momentum after position is overridden?

I've tried looking around already but everyone seems to have asked the question at least 5 years ago, and when I try to change `rigidbody.velocity` or `rigidbody.angularVelocity`, it says 'Component.rigidbody' is obsolete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html .. no they are not.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by this: "and now the answer they're all given - `rigidbody.velocity` and `rigidbody.angularVelocity` - are obselete."

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the docs: neither [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) nore [`Rigidbody.angularVelocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularVelocity.html) are "obsolete" ...

From a comment I saw you actually mean the `Component.rigidbody` which is obsolete -> You have to get it using [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) as any other component.

so simply go ahead and use

```
var rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
// or in case you get it from another object or component
//var rigidbody = otherObjectOrComponent.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```

---

btw you should also set the position not via the `Transform` component but rather using [`Rigidbody.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel momentum via velocity. It is not obselete:

```
Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>();

rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
```

Comment: It says 'Component.rigidbody' is obselete, even though I literally copied and pasted what you answered.

Comment: I've updated my code to be more reflective. rigidbody is not a native value you can pull from gameObjects anymore. You need to get the component explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Setting the velocity to Vector3.zero after the collision will work.  If you want to completely reset the ball, I would consider destroying the old ball and instantiating a new ball prefab.